# React, When i call handleSubmit() function i am sending data in application/json and multiform/data to backend but none data in student_image: null

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have to handle `application/json` and `multiform/data`, `student_image: fileState`, where `fileState` is `e.target.file[0]` value which is the image and other field are just `application/json` will store but this `fileState` need `multiform/data` even after changing also my image is not stored in a database. How to send data to API as my API accepts a list object. Any other ideas to store images along with other field values in `models.py` in DRF?

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
  let dataToSend = {};
          
  if (Array.isArray(formData)) {
    // Handle array data
    dataToSend = formData.map((formFields, index) => ({
    //     // Map the fields accordingly for each object in the array
    //     // Adjust this based on your data structure
      sn: formFields.sn,
      student_image: fileState,
      // Add other fields as needed
    }));
  } else if (typeof formData === 'object') {
    // dataToSend = [formData]
    // Handle object data
    dataToSend = [{
      // Map the fields accordingly for the object
      // Adjust this based on your data structure
      nepali: formData.nepali,
      international: formData.international,
      graduate_school_or_campus: formData.Campus,
      student_image: fileState,
      first_name: formData.first_name,
      middle_name: formData.middle_name,
      last_name: formData.last_name,
      email: formData.email,
      contact_no: formData.contact_no,
      gender: formData.gender,
      blood_group: formData.blood_group,
      ethnicity: formData.ethnicity,
      religion: formData.religion,
      date_of_birth_bs: formData.date_of_birth_bs,
      date_of_birth_ad: formData.date_of_birth_ad,
      batch: formData.batch,
      disability_status: formData.disability_status,
      sponsorship_status: formData.sponsorship_status,
      rural_district: formData.rural_district,
      martyr_lineage: formData.martyr_lineage,
      // citizenship_no: citizenship_no,
      // citizenship_image: formData.citizenship_image,
      school: formData.school,
      level: formData.level,
      program: formData.program,
      semester: formData.semester,
      status: formData.status,
      // 
      father_name: formData.father_name,
      mother_name: formData.mother_name,
      father_phone: formData.father_phone,
      mother_phone: formData.mother_phone,
      father_email: formData.father_email,
      mother_email: formData.mother_email,
      father_profession: formData.father_profession,
      mother_profession: formData.mother_profession,
      emergency_contact_name: formData.emergency_contact_name,
      emergency_contact_phone: formData.emergency_contact_phone,
      address: formData.address,
      relation_with_student: formData.relation_with_student,
      permanent_province: formData.permanent_province,
      permanent_district: formData.permanent_district,
      permanent_palika: formData.permanent_palika,
      permanent_ward_no: formData.permanent_ward_no,
      permanent_street_name: formData.permanent_street_name,
      permanent_house_no: formData.permanent_house_no,
      present_province: formData.present_province,
      present_district: formData.present_district,
      present_palika: formData.present_palika,
      present_ward_no: formData.present_ward_no,
      present_street_name: formData.present_street_name,
      present_house_no: formData.present_house_no,
      remarks: formData.remarks,
      education_history: formData.nestedForms,
      awardsMeritsScholarship: formData.nestedForms2
      // Add other fields as needed
    }];     
  }
        
  console.log('this is actual data', dataToSend);
  console.log('Type of dataToSend:', typeof dataToSend);
  // Now you can send a POST request with dataToSend to your APIw
  // For example using Axios or fetch
  // Replace 'YOUR_API_URL' with the actual API endpoint
  // Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with any authorization token you might need
  console.log("this is final data to sent", dataToSend)
  fetch(`${URL}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW', // Adjust the content type
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Adjust the content type
      'Authorization': `Bearer${Ttoken.access}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Response from API:', data);
      // Additional logic after receiving a response from the API
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      // Handle errors from the API call
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send both JSON and file data to a Django REST Framework (DRF) API, but you are facing issues with storing the image in the database. You are using fetch for making the API call. Likewise, you may find it hard to keep doing it in this way. By that meaning, you can send them in DRF's proper way.

### Solution

**Backend (Django DRF)**

In your models.py, use an `ImageField` for storing images. Django is able to deal with them by itself.

```py
    from django.db import models

    class Student(models.Model):
        student_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='student_images/')
        # other fields
```

*Ensure that your serializers.py also recognizes this field.*

**Frontend (JavaScript)**

You need to change the Content-Type and use `FormData` for sending both JSON and files.

Here's how you can modify your `handleSubmit` function:

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const formDataToSend = new FormData();

  if (typeof formData === 'object') {
    Object.keys(formData).forEach(key => {
      formDataToSend.append(key, formData[key]);
    });
  }
  
  // Add the file to the FormData object
  formDataToSend.append('student_image', fileState);

  // Remove the 'Content-Type' from the headers
  fetch(`${URL}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${Ttoken.access}`
    },
    body: formDataToSend,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Response from API:', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
};
```

*Quick Points:*

- Removed `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` because the browser will
  set this automatically when using `FormData`.
- Used `FormData` to send both file and other data. Note that
  `.append()` can be used to add each field individually.
- `ImageField` is used in Django model for handling image files.
- Token for authorization remains unchanged.

With these changes, you should be able to send files and JSON data to your DRF API and store them accordingly.

### Why?

The overarching issue was the misalignment between the data format you were sending and what your API is designed to handle. Specifically:

- You were attempting to send both JSON and file data in a single API
  request using the 'application/json' content type, which wouldn't
  suffice for file uploads.
- The backend wasn't specified, but it should be prepared to handle
  this kind of multipart data. A suitable field type like `ImageField`
  in Django Rest Framework's model would be required to handle the
  image data efficiently.

These discrepancies made it difficult to store the image and JSON data in your database effectively.

### Other solutions

If you do want to keep your old way and still include images in your data payload, a common approach is to encode your images as Base64 strings. This method simplifies the handling of your data by allowing you to send the image as a string alongside other fields, making it more compatible across different platforms and browsers. However, there are trade-offs such as increased data size, approximately 33% larger than the original file, and additional CPU usage for the encoding and decoding process. I do not overall recommend, but choose what best suits your setup.

**Backend**

In terms of implementation, you could modify your Django model to use a `TextField` to store the Base64-encoded image.

```py
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    student_image_base64 = models.TextField()
```

**Frontend**

For the frontend part, you could use JavaScript's `FileReader` to read the image file and get its Base64 representation. Then, include this string in the JSON object you're sending in your fetch API call. Here's how you could adapt your `handleSubmit` function:

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileState);
  reader.onload = async () => {
    const base64String = reader.result.split(',')[1];
    let dataToSend = {
      student_image_base64: base64String,
      // your other fields here
    };

    await fetch(`${URL}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${Ttoken.access}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Response from API:', data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  };
};
```

With this approach, you're essentially converting the image into a format that can be easily sent with other types of data, thus simplifying the overall data handling process for a price. Choose what better suits your setup and ideals.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i get following error 
Response from API: {error: 'Data should be a list of objects.'}

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback. Wanted to know: are you knew in Django? Also it seems the API expects a list of objects rather than a single object, as indicated by the error message "Data should be a list of objects." 
```const handleSubmit = () => {
  let objectToSend = { /* ... Your Data ... */ };

  // Ensure it is in a list format
  let dataToSend = [objectToSend];

  // ... (fetch call remains the same)
};```
On the Django, ensure your API views are set up to handle a list of objects. You can use DRF's `many=True` flag during deserialization to indicate that you're expecting a list

Comment: @AMRITSHAHI The API expects an array (list in Python terms). If you are sending just one student's data but the API expects a list, you can send it as a list containing a single object, as the python code I presented above fixes. By ensuring that the data is sent in a list and that the API is configured to receive such data, you should be able to resolve the issue. This is all about backend configuration itself.